# Create a Word Cloud in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dashboard, word-cloud, tag-cloud

I'm trying to create a `Word Cloud Generator` that displays the words from my collected data using python. The code here reads the data from my file (`raw_data6`) and display the word cloud, however, I'm asking if there's a possibility to create a search box so that the user will enter a word and search, and then the word cloud will display all the words related to the user search.

So basically, when the user will search a word for example (`Poverty`) in the search box, the word cloud will show all the words related to poverty.

**My questions here: if this is possible, what is the code to implement this?**

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #to display our wordcloud
from PIL import Image #to load our image
import numpy as np #to get the color of our image

text = open('../input/data-try/raw_data6.csv', mode="r", encoding="utf-8").read()
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

custom_mask = np.array(Image.open('../input/twitterpic/Twitter-PNG-Image.png'))
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white",
               stopwords=stopwords,
               mask = custom_mask,
              )
wc.generate(text)
image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(custom_mask)
wc.recolor(color_func = image_colors)

plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAm8F.png) is a display of the word cloud after running the code above.

Comment: do you use GUI framework like Tkinter, PyQt? Do you display it on web page? Without GUI/HTML you may only use standard `input()` to ask for word. And run in loop if you want to search many times.

Comment: how do you recognize "related" words? Do you have some special column in CSV for this information? If you don't have it then first you have to decide how to recognize "related" words.

Comment: @furas So, for the first question, I created a web-based dashboard using pycharm (python & html) so users can view data and i want to add the word cloud to the interface. The CSV file contains the collected data (two columns: first, the keyword that we used to collect the tweets from twitter using tweepy, and the second column is the tweets itself).

Comment: @furas, also the word cloud will only read the tweets, so I don't know how to make the code reads an input from the user and search through the tweets for related words (the user input could be any word not necessary from the keyword list).

Comment: but first you have to answer: What are  "related" words for you? Words in the same tweet? Similar words from some tool for NLP (natural language processing)? If you don't know what means "related'` then you can't search it.

Comment: if "related" means other words from tweet which have searched word then you need only normal `for`-loop and `if word in tweet` to filter tweets.

Answer (score -1):

Try this once:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

text = open('/home/student/Desktop/Python/Data/lyrics.txt', 'r').read()
stopwords = set(open('/home/student/Desktop/Python/Data/stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split())

custom_mask = np.array(Image.open("/home/student/Desktop/Python/Data/mask.png"))
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=2000, mask=custom_mask, stopwords=stopwords)

wc.generate(text)
image_color = ImageColorGenerator(custom_mask)
wc.recolor(color_func=image_color)

plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

**You can change your path as your wish**

Comment: describe it. what is different in your code?

Comment: where do you ask for word and search "related" words?